# Visual Studio Stuck During Installation

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I've seen many posts with people having the exact same problem I'm currently having, and none of the solutions I've seen there have worked for me. Here's the basic run down of the problem.

I'm installing Visual Studio 2017, and the installer keeps getting stuck on the same step `Applying Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.JustInTime`, I have tried restarting the installer, restarting my computer, completely purging my system of all VS2017 files and restarting the process from the beginning, and disabling my anti-virus, none of these attempts have works. Any thoughts on how I might go about fixing this problem?

Comment: Can you give us some info on what you've already tried? did you try manually registering the jit complier as described here? https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/14876/installer-is-frozen-at-80-for-hours.html

Comment: @FrankThomas, I attempted the use the command that solution offered, no success there, and I was unable to find if that was the command that froze in my case.